# Are two representations $V, W$ isomorphic if $\left<\chi_V, \chi_W\right> > 1$ for the inner product of their characters?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, characters

I know from Schur's lemma(s) that if $V, W$ are two isomorphic irreducible representations of a group $G$, then  $\left<\chi_V, \chi_W\right> = 1$. This is because the dimension of the space of intertwining maps between $V$ and $W$ is equal to $\left<\chi_V, \chi_W\right>$. Then, what if $\left<\chi_V, \chi_W\right> > 1$? Then we know that there are multidimensional intertwining maps between $V$ and $W$. Does it then follows that $V \cong W$?

Comment: What would happen if $W=V\oplus V$?

Comment: @MatthewTowers My knowledge of direct sums in linear algebra is a bit shaky, so can you help me out here? If we assume that $\left<\chi_V, \chi_V\right> = 1$, then $\left<\chi_V, \chi_W\right> = \left<\chi_V, 2\chi_V\right> = 2$.